# How to tune hyperparameters for LLE?

Tags: scikit-learn, dimensionality-reduction, unsupervised-learning, hyperparameter, manifold-learning

I'm running LLE using Scikit-Learn (with the `LocallyLinearEmbedding` class), but there are a few hyperparameters and I would like to use grid search with cross-validation to tune them. Unfortunately, I don't know what performance measure to use for that. I was thinking of using the reconstruction error, but the `LocallyLinearEmbedding` class has no `inverse_transform()` method.

What's a good way to tune LLE (using Scikit-Learn)?

Here's the code I'm using to perform LLE on the swiss roll dataset.

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_swiss_roll
from sklearn.manifold import LocallyLinearEmbedding

X, t = make_swiss_roll(n_samples=1000, noise=0.2, random_state=0)

lle = LocallyLinearEmbedding(n_neighbors=10, n_components=2, random_state=0)
Z = lle.fit_transform(X)
```

I then plot the result using matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter(Z[:, 0], Z[:, 1], c=t)
plt.show()
```

Looking at the plot, it seems that `n_neighbors=10` is a reasonably good setting. With a lower value, I get more or less line segments, and with higher values the different layers of the swiss roll start to overlap. I'd like to find this without having to visualize the dataset.

Comment: There is an attribute ```reconstruction_error_``` which could be used, although i don't know how to make this compatible with the given gridsearch functionality. But there is also the more general question: what are you using this embedding for? I suspect, that it's a prestep for some other algorithm (classification, regression, ...). In this case, it would be much more attractive to optimize the combined output of these two-steps, which could easily be done with gridsearch on a piped expression.

Comment: Thanks @sascha, somehow I missed this attribute. To answer your question, I am mostly playing around, not using this for a concrete project yet. I agree with your point about evaluating based on the overall objective. But this might come in handy for an unsupervised task, I guess.